# Simple GetElementById issue

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript I'm having a very simple problem. I just don't get what's going on.

I just want to add a class to a `<div>` tag but it's not working

This is my javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("main");
element.classList.add("hidden");
```

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/72o6j6r0/

Comment: `getElementById` selects an element by its **ID**, not a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, the method `document.getElementById()` returns an HTML element by using the id of the element

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            This is my main content to be hidden
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("main");
element.classList.add("hidden");
```

If you want to use the class attribute to select your elements rather than the id you can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName()
```

and then loop over the results

Here is a JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mko3uf9f/